# How to interpret "git branch -a" output

Tags: git

May be a trivial question, but I am stuck:

```
git branch -a
```

returns

```
features/A
features/B
* master
remotes/m/master -> base/master
remotes/features/C
```

(So current branch is master)

Question is: How to interpret the `->` at the line

```
remotes/m/master -> base/master
```

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong, but I'm pretty sure this is just telling you that the primary branch on your remote is considered `master`. Again, I could be totally wrong.

Comment: I think you are correct - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branch-Management at §Changing the master branch name . branches have been renamed locally but not remotely if I catch it well

Comment: It looks like a symbolic branch to me. You can create it with the unlikely command `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/m/master refs/heads/base/master`. No idea how it got there, maybe a rogue remote server? Anyway you can probably delete it with `git symbolic-ref --delete refs/remotes/m/master`.